# Wrong EP on an .elf CrackMe

Tags: ida, elf, crackme, entry-point

I am trying to solve an elf CrackMe. I opened it with IDA Pro and I saw start function is on address 0x1E8. I opened the elf with HxD and I saw entry point is 0x1E9 (and no results on file for 01E8)...

If I run on Kali terminal:

```
readelf --symbols CrackMe
```

I don't get any result. If I run:

```
readelf --sections Crackme
```

I get over 20 sections.

If I try to execute the binary on Kali terminal:

```
./CrackMe
```

I get

```
zsh: exec format error.
```

I changed manually the byte of entry point that is different with HxD, E9 --> E8, but I don't get any different results when I execute all again using the edited file.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Can you pls post the crackme?

Comment: The file could be stripped and doesn't match the architecture of your kali vm. You could run `file CrackMe` to see what's breaking.